# SQL Response to JSON for non-trivial query

Tags: orientdb

I have this query that works in studio, which for a given worker, returns those other workers that recommend them.

[Worker:V] -> [RecommendedBy:E] -> [Worker:V]

Im constructing SQL to return some selected data from the E and the V that is recommending.  So below works

```
SELECT  out('RecommendedBy').firstName as recommendedByFirstName,
        out('RecommendedBy').lastName as recommendedByLastName,
        out('RecommendedBy').@rid as recommendedByRID,
        outE('RecommendedBy').recommendationHeadline as headline
FROM Worker WHERE userName  = 'paulw';
```

How can I convert the response to the above adhoc query to a single JSON object using @this.toJSON?  I can get something like below to work Ok:

```
SELECT @this.toJson('rid,version,fetchPlan:in_RecommendedBy:1') FROM Worker WHERE userName = 'paulw';
```

but not for the first SQL.  Any help appreciated thanks!

Comment: You can find detailed fetchPlan documentation here: http://orientdb.com/docs/last/Fetching-Strategies.html

Comment: Try: `SELECT @this.toJson('fetchPlan:out_RecommendedBy:-1') FROM Worker WHERE userName = 'paulw';`

Comment: Thanks for replying - it is the first query in this post I need help with not the second (second works, its the first I am wondering the best way to return as JSON).  In the first, I am only wanting a select few attributes on the matching Edge and Vextices....was looking at using 'Match' operation?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand what you need, is this useful?

```
SELECT @this.toJson() FROM (
SELECT  out('RecommendedBy').firstName as recommendedByFirstName,
        out('RecommendedBy').lastName as recommendedByLastName,
        out('RecommendedBy').@rid as recommendedByRID,
        outE('RecommendedBy').recommendationHeadline as headline
FROM Worker WHERE userName  = 'paulw')
```